# Online Correspondence Chess Competition

Tags: tournament, online, correspondence-chess

What is a free and easy-to-use website for organizing an online correspondence chess competition for kids?

Comment: For children, a more immediate rhythm of play may be better than that of correspondence chess, which can be 30 days for ten movements or also five days for every ten movements (each day passed subtracts from the accumulated and when reaching the tenth movement , days are added to the counter).

Comment: 1 day per move would be the best option for correspondence chess.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how many kids have the patience for correspondence chess. I always preferred 10-20 minutes as a kid to think things through without dragging it out forever.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the [echecsemail](https://echecsemail.com) website. You can create round-robin tournaments for up to 9 players. For bigger player-pools, you'll have to split them in groups (or maybe talk to the admins).

They also offer the possibility of choosing an alternative starting position (for opening practice purposes mainly)

I hope those kids speak French, though!

Answer (score 2):

You can play correspondence chess (and I believe set up tournaments) on chess.com. While the site is free, paid members do get more features. I'm not sure if any of these features would be relevant to a correspondence tournament though.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.chess-server.net/en/ is another option. 100% free!!! 10-20 different languages are available. The director, Ortwin Paetzold, is extremely helpful. Just contact him.

[image: LSS languages]